# How to get the "hosts" of the Google Chrome history entries

Tags: google-chrome, history

I know I can export the history and import it to Firefox.

In what method can I get every visited `host` of every URL of the chrome history. Host means roughly the domain of any URL.

[*What is host?*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fzTr.png)

To put it another way - anyway of doing this:

**Input - the history** (the export file or any other way)

```
abc.com/1
abc.com/3
google.com/search/v
```

**desired output**

```
abc.com
google.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[obsidianforensics/hindsight](https://github.com/obsidianforensics/hindsight)**

Internet history forensics for Google Chrome/Chromium.
Hindsight is a free tool for analyzing web artifacts. It started with the browsing history of the Google Chrome web browser and has expanded to support other Chromium-based applications (with more to come!). Hindsight can parse a number of different types of web artifacts, including URLs, download history, cache records, bookmarks, autofill records, saved passwords, preferences, browser extensions, HTTP cookies, and Local Storage records (HTML5 cookies). Once the data is extracted from each file, it is correlated with data from other history files and placed in a timeline.

It has a simple web UI - to start it, run `hindsight_gui.py` (or on Windows, the packaged `hindsight_gui.exe`) and visit `http://localhost:8080` in a browser.

Comment: I like this most.

Answer (score 0):

**[BrowsingHistoryView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/browsing_history_view.html)**

[image]

BrowsingHistoryView is a utility that reads the history data of different Web browsers (Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, Microsoft Edge, Opera) and displays the browsing history of all these Web browsers in one table. The browsing history table includes the following information: Visited URL, Title, Visit Time, Visit Count, Web browser and User Profile. BrowsingHistoryView allows you to watch the browsing history of all user profiles in a running system, as well as to get the browsing history from external hard drive.
You can also export the browsing history into csv/tab-delimited/html/xml file from the user interface, or from command-line, without displaying any user interface.